# How to configure PHPunit test results output to HTML file?

Tags: php, html, testing, phpunit, report

I'm using phpunit for testing and I really need html reports in HTML format.
Please show me the simplest way or code example.

Answer (score 7):

Built-in PHPUnit, you can generate a report in HTML using the `--testdox-html <output file>` option. The output is very rudimentary.

> `--testdox-html` is backward-compatibility,
> but without intention to be ever improved, see: [#4605](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4605)

Alternatively you can generate the junit xml output using the `--log-junit <output file>` option and transform the xml output to html with an xsl-script, e.g. the one from [phing](https://www.phing.info/trac/browser/etc) (you will need [`phpunit-noframes.xsl`](https://www.phing.info/trac/browser/etc/phpunit-noframes.xsl) and [`str.replace.function.xsl`](https://www.phing.info/trac/browser/etc/str.replace.function.xsl)) using an xsltprocessor like [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html). This will give a little bit more information.

For the ultimate power there are frontends for phpunit which displays the test results in the browser as HTML, this could be worth a look as well:

- [VisualPHPUnit](http://visualphpunit.github.io/VisualPHPUnit/) (resp. [at Github](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit))
- [PHPUnit_Html](https://github.com/nickturner/PHPUnit_Html)

Comment: VisualPHPUnit docs are really poor. For last few hours I have tried to make it work - no luck.